# How to convert sourceSets to Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following code:

```
    sourceSets {
    create("main") {
        manifest.srcFile("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
        java.srcDirs("src/main/java")
        resources.srcDirs("srs/main/others")
        res.srcDirs("src/main/res")
        assets.srcDirs("src/main/assets")
        jniLibs.srcDirs("jniLibs")
    }
    create("production") {
        manifest.srcFile("src/production/AndroidManifest.xml")
        java.srcDirst += ("src/production/java")
        res.srcDirs += ("src/production/res")
    }
    create("canary") {
        manifest.srcFile("src/canary/AndroidManifest.xml")
        java.srcDirs += ("src/canary/java")
        res.srcDirs += ("src/canary/res")
    }
}
```

I've tried browsing the web but still can't figure out how to convert `+=` "production" and "canary" to Kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
sourceSets {
    create("main") {
        manifest.srcFile("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
        java.srcDirs("src/main/java")
        resources.srcDirs("src/main/others")
        res.srcDirs("src/main/res")
        assets.srcDirs("src/main/assets")
        jniLibs.srcDirs("jniLibs")
    }
    create("production") {
        manifest.srcFile("src/production/AndroidManifest.xml")
        java.srcDirs("src/production/java")
        res.srcDirs("src/production/res")
    }
    create("canary") {
        manifest.srcFile("src/canary/AndroidManifest.xml")
        java.srcDirs("src/canary/java")
        res.srcDirs("src/canary/res")
    }
}
```

}